# ActionScript 3 mx:HorizontalList set columns per row

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

I have a Flex HorizontalList like so:

```
<mx:HorizontalList id="myList" width="1462" height="878" columnCount="3" rowHeight="475" columnWidth="350" dataProvider="{floorPlans}" itemRenderer="FloorplanItems">


                                    </mx:HorizontalList>
```

I am trying to set 3 columns per a row, I thought columnCount would do it, but either its not working and or is not doing what I thought it would be doing.

How can I set 3 columns per a row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mx:HorizontalList is meant to list items in one row. The columnCount property is used to define the number of columns appearing without a need to scroll.

I suggest that you use Spark List "s:List" instead and define tile layout inside it in addition to specifying item renderer width that fits your needs.

```
<s:List id="addressesList" width="100%"  height="100%" itemRenderer="FloorplanItems">
            <s:layout>
                <s:TileLayout id="tileLayout" horizontalAlign="justify" columnAlign="justifyUsingWidth"/>
            </s:layout>
</s:List>
```

Hope this helps,
goodluck.